# Do you need a Mac to develop ios apps with Rhodes / frameworks

Tags: iphone, ios, rhomobile, rhodes

I know you need a mac to develop native iOS apps . 
However, I am currently trying to use Rhodes framework for developing apps and am wondering if I need to buy a mac eventually to be able to compile for iOS etc ?.

Or probably for testing etc, since I believe iOS doesnt have an emulator

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You actually do have to run macos. You don't have to buy a mac but if you can install osx on your machine or if you buy a hackintosh, You shouldn't have any problem. As far as I can say, there is an emulator and it is quite possible to make it run on windows and compile things.

I read somewhere that you can do most of the job with pain on windows, but you'll end up singing your package on osx. While as funny as it is. Someone gave the idea to run osx in a vm. You could probably do that if you really need to.

Anyway the simplest way to do that is to buy a mac, but if you really reject the idea to spend money on a mac, you could find a way to do all you need without a mac. But you almost definitely need to install osx.

Comment: all right ..would buy a mac ..  you can love them hate them .. in the end you buy them :)

Comment: not sure, wouldn't buy one just for iOS. It's not as if you had to use some kind of hardware signed keys that exists only on mac computers. Look up here, it's apparently possible to do with some kits. http://geeknizer.com/how-to-develop-iphone-apps-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a mac with OSX to compile a Rhodes app for iOS, you can use [RhoHub](https://app.rhohub.com).

You can upload your Apple developer key to this service at it will generate the binary for you.

But at the end, to test and debug your app, having an OSX machine available it's better.